# loop through each textbox on page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to loop through each textbox on a web form and clear any text within the control..

I've tried:

```
    Dim ctrl As TextBox

    For Each ctrl In form1.Controls
        ctrl.Text = ""
    Next
```

but I amm getting an error message:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
For Each control As Object In form1.Controls
        If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then
            control.Text = ""
        End If

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
For Each c As Control In Page.Controls
If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
    TryCast(c, TextBox).Text = [String].Empty
End If
Next
```